# SQL 2008 getting connection timeouts - Not a DBA

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, connection-timeout

Wall of text (my apologies, but you'll need to read it all):

Error Message: ***Database Error:  Connection Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed while attempting to consume the pre-login handshake acknowledgement.  This could be because the pre-login handshake failed or the server was una***

Environment:
Virtual VMware Server 2008R2 SP1, running SQL 2008 SP3
32GB RAM - about 50 Databases
10Gb LAN connection, datastore storage provided by SSD SAN.

Application is CSTS connecting to SQL Server "DIRGE".
The application is configured to connect to another application for document retrieval "Onbase", who's database is also stored on DIRGE.

Throughout the day, CSTS will get connection time-outs.  It's usually in spurts, so if one user is getting a timeout, usually someone else is getting one as well.

SQL has 28GB of the 32GB allocated.  Memory utilization is a consistent >95%.
We cannot add more RAM as 2008R2 standard doesn't see more than 32GB.
CPU utilization was very high at times and the trend was it was getting more and more utilization, so we added a second CPU (2 sockets, 4 cores per socket).

I've scoured the event logs and the SQL logs, and the CSTS error logs looking for a commonality.  I'm finding very little.  I've resolved all the event log errors, no joy.

NOTE: Onbase server also gets connection time outs to SQL, so I don't believe it's application specific.

Scheduled Events:
Logs are backed up at 8am, 11a, 2pm, 5pm.
There's a SSIS package that runs every 15 minutes and takes about 8 minutes to run.  However, I did not find any correlation to the timeouts.
There are maintenance plans that run after hours as well.

IP4 and 6 are both enabled.
Clients are referencing the database server by IP, so it's not a name resolution issue.
IP Protocols are enabled, static set to port 1433.
I ran a portqry from the Onbase server to TCP 143 and UDP 1434 and it IS listening.

We have a Solarwinds Database Analyzer running and watching this server; it says CPU and RAM are issues.  I can get more details from it if anyone is interested.

I've google-fu'd the heck out of this and I just can't seem to find a good answer.  From my searching, it seems this is a networking issue, but we've watched the network and I'm not seeing anything that would be the cause.  Throughput is very little overall.

I will say this: The ONBASE server is on a different subnet than DIRGE, but I've ran a test DB connection using the name, named pipe and IP and they all work without issue.

The problem is I'm on a DBA so I'm learning this on the fly (I'm a Sr Systems Engineer).

I'm curious if someone has a suggestion on how to hunt this down.

Comment: I'm assuming you have SQL Server login success/fail logged and you've correlated failures to windows event log and found nothing. Can you setup a perfmon trace that captures login events along with CPU, memory and disk utilizations? That is a relatively easy and lightweight way to determine if there is correlation between login failure and resource utilization. Also, make sure DAC is enabled. If you can jump in when the failures are happening, try logging with a regular connection via SSMS and SQLCMD, try again with a DAC connection if the former fails. Let us know what you find.

Comment: Thanks SQLmojoe.  Yes, I can set up a perfmon trace for that.
I'll post the results when I get it going.